# Does iOS store DNS and if so, how do I reset it after a server transfer?

Tags: ios, caching, dns, server

Does iOS store DNS and if so, how do I reset it after a server transfer? I have an App that is released, and before I migrate by server to a different IP, I want to make sure I know if the people using my App will have any issues with the API calls in the App. Any knowledge would be appreciated. Thank You for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a DNS expert, but not so much for iOS.  So this answer is how the DNS is intended to work.  I can't say whether or not iOS got this right (but they have a better reputation for rightness than some others I won't mention).

In the DNS each RR (that's Resource Record, the basic unit in the DNS, your address [assuming you only have one] is in a single RR) has a TTL, which specifies how long it will be good for.  In normal operation you set these to a fairly long time (at least a few hours, often several days).  When things aren't changing, this says how long the DNS client should hold the data before querying again.  When you're contemplating a change, you set the TTL down low (say a few minutes) in advance, and then you can make the change at the right time and since no hosts should hold on to the old data for longer than that lowered TTL, you know that everyone should have the new data within that time.  The reason you use higher TTLs normally is to lower the demands on both your server and your (and everyone who connects to you) Internet connection.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed to know :)